# Best way to compare bunch of Constant Strings (keys) with a Map

Tags: java, collections

So, I have a Map (String, String) which I receive this map can have about 600-800 entries. My task is to retrieve only about 60-120 (based on some logic) of those pairs based on the keys (constant strings).

Right now I have created a List of the required Keys, I am iterating the Map I receive and pulling out required pairs into another Map and passing it on. This works, but the code looks horrible.

There surely has to be a better way of doing this. Any suggestions?

I thought of using contains instead of matching keys, but my requirement is for exact matches. Yes, I read about using RegEx for exact matches, so that can be used as a last resort.

What I need help with:
1. Better way to store required keys than having them in a List. This list of keys are going to be a constant. Having a list of 60-120 strings hardcoded into a List looks horrible.
2. Fastest (time) way to compare the said list and pull out required pairs.

My code:

```
List <String> keysToCheck = new ArrayList<String>();
keysToCheck.add("attrib1");
...
keysToCheck.add("attribN");

Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String,  String>();
for (String key : keysToCheck) {
    if(mapRcvd.containsKey(key)) {
    newMap.put(key, mapRcvd.get(key));
    }
}
```

I am looking for solutions which would be quicker, as this would be a very small part of a larger application. I am good with having to write a lot of code to achieve that.

Comment: Can you share some code, it´s easier to look for improvements.

Comment: Sure will do. Its a pain to have then typed out on mobile.

Comment: `my requirement is for exact matches` What do you mean? `contains` method should work fine

Comment: Would a data class with 60-120 (possible `Optional<...>`) fields make sense in your case? Or - less likely - enums for the keys, and an `EnumSet`/`EnumMap`. Hard to say without code.

Comment: You already use one of the fastest ways. You can avoid looking up each key twice, by omitting `containsKey`: `String value = mapRcvd.get(key); if(value != null) newMap.put(key, value);`. You don’t need to write a series of `add` calls to initialize your list, just use `List<String> keysToCheck = Arrays.asList("attrib1", …, "attribN");`. Starting with Java 9, you can use `List.of` instead of `Arrays.asList`, which will return a truly immutable list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all constant keys in a file, where each line contains one key. Then you can get all required keys like:

```
List<String> requiredKeys = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH_TO_FILE_WITH_KEYS))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now get map with required keys using stream `filter` method:

```
 Map<String, String> collect = mapRcvd.entrySet().stream()  // get stream of map entries
            .filter(entry -> requiredKeys.contains(entry.getKey()))  // filter only such entries which has required key
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));  // collect all filtered entries into new map
```

More about [`Collectors.toMap`](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-java-8-streams-collectors-tomap.html), [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)

**Update:** while getting map with required keys *may* seem more compact, the for-loop with `containsKey` method in your example is faster than `contains`. You should probably use the advice @Holger left in the comments

Comment: Thanks for the response. The second part is too much to process. Any chance you can break it down in words to say what it is doing in parts?

Comment: @WhiteBird Comments added. Also you can read more about stream https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/ Glad to help!

Comment: You’ve replaced the fast map lookups of the question’s code with slow `List.contains` operations. Not really an improvement.